# Supervisord & Laravel - has been attempted too many times or run too long

Tags: laravel, queue, supervisord

I have a problem with supervisord, and particularly when trying to have multiple workers.

Background:

- My website only has one intensive job, and I want to be able to process multiples of these at the same time (multiple users at the same time).
- I use the `supervisord.conf` shown below to do this:

```
command=sudo php /var/www/.../laravel/artisan queue:work --timeout=900  
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
numprocs=8                                 
priority=999                  
autostart=true                
autorestart=true              
startsecs=1                  
startretries=3                
user=root
redirect_stderr=true         
stdout_logfile=/var/www/.../laravel/worker.log
```

The result is as follows:

1. The job is triggered;
2. Job created in `jobs` table in database
3. Within a second job is removed from `jobs` table, and added 7 times in the `jobs_failed` table.
4. The 8th (or 1st?) worker completes the job successfully.

What am I doing wrong here? I assume something in `supervisord.conf` is causing this, or in the command I am using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out what the issue is here; using `database` as queue is great for testing, but not suitable for production. Changed over to redis and everything works OK.